# How to validate a correct domain name and sub domain in php

Tags: php, regex, validation, dns

How to remove **www** and **validate** a valid domain name.

**Valid Domain**

```
domain.com
subdomain.domain.com
sub-domain.domain.com
```

**Invalid Domain**

```
www.domain.com
www.subdomain.domain.com
http://www.domain.com/
http://www.subdomain.com/
www.domain.com/folder/
```

**How the code?**

```
$domain ='www.domain.com/folder/';
if() {
// validate here
}
```

Comment: www.domain.com, www.subdomain.domain.com - what is invalid here?

Comment: Why are you treating the www subdomain differently to every other subdomain? It has no special meaning, other then being conventionally used for websites, but conventions relate to other subdomains too (e.g. ftp, smtp, imap, etc)

Comment: It's just for my record. I want to store the domain without to have the www.

Comment: @wow You should be notified that on some domains the `www` subdomain is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, manually strip out the www. then just make sure it is in the form domain.tld or something.domain.tld

`$domain = str_replace('www.','',$domain);`

`if(preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}/',$domain))
//valid domain`

Comment: You seem to be getting your `.` and `,` mixed up there … and TLDs are not limited to 4 characters … and the question appears to ask that hostnames with `www` be rejected, not normalised.

Comment: something.museum? 6 chars in the TLD. You could also add another check, the domain name and the sub domain name must have at most 63 chars.

Comment: The domain string will break if you use str_replace and there is a domain name like this: `domainwww.com` since you remove all instances of `www.`from the string the result will end up looking like this `domaincom`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Validate/Zend_Validate_Hostname.html  (`Zend_Validate_Hostname`) class. I think that you can use it outside of Zend Framework, with a minor tuning.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(d+)?/?/i', $url)) {
    echo "Your url is ok.";
} else {
    echo "Wrong url.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $subdomain) || substr_count($subdomain,'--') >= 1) {
                echo "Invalid Subdomain";
              }
              else{ 
                 echo Valid Subdomain; 
              }
```